# How to alter creative commons dialog to your local language in dspace?

Tags: dspace

[image]
You can see that a dialog box has the English options but it was to be Portuguese.

How to alter this dialog box options to your local language?

**Configurations:**

default.language = pt_BR   
 
default.locale = pt_BR

webui.supported.locales = pt_BR

cc.license.jurisdiction = br  
 
cc.license.locale = pt_BR

```
%--

        The contents of this file are subject to the license and copyright
        detailed in the LICENSE and NOTICE files at the root of the source
        tree and available online at

        http://www.dspace.org/license/

    --%>
    <%--
      - Show the user the Creative Commons license which they may grant or reject
      -
      - Attributes to pass in:
      -    cclicense.exists   - boolean to indicate CC license already exists
      --%>

    <%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %>

    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt"
        prefix="fmt" %>

    <%@ page import="org.dspace.core.Context" %>
    <%@ page import="org.dspace.app.webui.servlet.SubmissionController" %>
    <%@ page import="org.dspace.submit.AbstractProcessingStep" %>
    <%@ page import="org.dspace.app.util.SubmissionInfo" %>
    <%@ page import="org.dspace.app.webui.util.UIUtil" %>
    <%@ page import="org.dspace.license.CreativeCommons" %>
    <%@ page import="org.dspace.core.ConfigurationManager" %>
    <%@ page import="org.dspace.license.CCLicense"%>
    <%@ page import="java.util.Collection"%>

    <%@ taglib uri="http://www.dspace.org/dspace-tags.tld" prefix="dspace" %>

    <%
        request.setAttribute("LanguageSwitch", "hide");

        // Obtain DSpace context
        Context context = UIUtil.obtainContext(request);    

        //get submission information object
        SubmissionInfo subInfo = SubmissionController.getSubmissionInfo(context, request);

        Boolean lExists = (Boolean)request.getAttribute("cclicense.exists");
        boolean licenseExists = (lExists == null ? false : lExists.booleanValue());

        Collection<CCLicense> cclicenses = (Collection<CCLicense>)request.getAttribute("cclicense.licenses");

        String licenseURL = "";
        if(licenseExists)
            licenseURL = CreativeCommons.getLicenseURL(subInfo.getSubmissionItem().getItem());
    %>

    <dspace:layout style="submission"
                   locbar="off"
                   navbar="off"
                   titlekey="jsp.submit.creative-commons.title"
                   nocache="true">

        <form name="foo" id="license_form" action="<%= request.getContextPath() %>/submit" method="post" onkeydown="return disableEnterKey(event);">

            <jsp:include page="/submit/progressbar.jsp"/>

            <%-- <h1>Submit: Use a Creative Commons License</h1> --%>
            <h1><fmt:message key="jsp.submit.creative-commons.heading"/></h1>

            <p class="help-block"><fmt:message key="jsp.submit.creative-commons.info1"/></p>

        <div class="row">
            <label class="col-md-2"><fmt:message key="jsp.submit.creative-commons.license"/></label>
            <span class="col-md-8">
                <select name="licenseclass_chooser" id="licenseclass_chooser" class="form-control">
                        <option
                            value="webui.Submission.submit.CCLicenseStep.select_change"><fmt:message key="jsp.submit.creative-commons.select_change"/></option>
                        <% if(cclicenses!=null) { 
                                for(CCLicense cclicense : cclicenses) { %>
                                    <option
                                        value="<%= cclicense.getLicenseId()%>"><%= cclicense.getLicenseName()%></option>                        
                        <%      }
                            }%>
                        <option
                            value="webui.Submission.submit.CCLicenseStep.no_license"><fmt:message key="jsp.submit.creative-commons.no_license"/></option>
                 </select>
            </span>
        </div>
        <% if(licenseExists) { %>
        <div class="row" id="current_creativecommons">      
            <label class="col-md-2"><fmt:message key="jsp.submit.creative-commons.license.current"/></label>
            <span class="col-md-8">
                <a href="<%=licenseURL %>"><%=licenseURL %></a>
            </span>     
        </div>
        <% } %>
        <div style="display:none;" id="creativecommons_response">       
        </div>
        <br/>
            <%-- Hidden fields needed for SubmissionController servlet to know which step is next--%>
        <%= SubmissionController.getSubmissionParameters(context, request) %>

        <input type="hidden" name="cc_license_url" value="<%=licenseURL %>" />
        <input type="submit" id="submit_grant" name="submit_grant" value="submit_grant" style="display: none;" />   
        <%
            int numButton = 2 + (!SubmissionController.isFirstStep(request, subInfo)?1:0) + (licenseExists?1:0);

        %>
        <div class="row col-md-<%= 2*numButton %> pull-right btn-group">
                    <%  //if not first step, show "Previous" button
                        if(!SubmissionController.isFirstStep(request, subInfo))
                        { %>
                <input class="btn btn-default col-md-<%= 12 / numButton %>" type="submit" name="<%=AbstractProcessingStep.PREVIOUS_BUTTON%>" value="<fmt:message key="jsp.submit.general.previous"/>" />
                    <%  } %>

                <input class="btn btn-default col-md-<%= 12 / numButton %>" type="submit" name="<%=AbstractProcessingStep.CANCEL_BUTTON%>" value="<fmt:message key="jsp.submit.general.cancel-or-save.button"/>"/>
                <input class="btn btn-primary col-md-<%= 12 / numButton %>" type="submit" name="<%=AbstractProcessingStep.NEXT_BUTTON%>" value="<fmt:message key="jsp.submit.general.next"/>" />
        </div>
        </form>




        <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
    jQuery("#licenseclass_chooser").change(function() {
        var make_id = jQuery(this).find(":selected").val();
        var request = jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '<%=request.getContextPath()%>/json/creativecommons?license=' + make_id
        });
        request.done(function(data){
            jQuery("#creativecommons_response").empty();
            var result = data.result;
            for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                var id = result[i].id;            
                var label = result[i].label;
                var description = result[i].description;
                var htmlCC = " <div class='form-group'><span class='help-block' title='"+description+"'>"+label+"&nbsp;<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign'></i></span>"
                var typefield = result[i].type;
                if(typefield=="enum") {             
                    jQuery.each(result[i].fieldEnum, function(key, value) {
                        htmlCC += "<label class='radio-inline' for='"+id+"-"+key+"'>";
                        htmlCC += "<input placeholder='"+value+"' type='radio' id='"+id+"-"+key+"' name='"+id+"_chooser' value='"+key+"' required/>"+value+ "</label>";
                    });
                }
                htmlCC += "</div>";
                jQuery("#creativecommons_response").append(htmlCC);                
            }

            jQuery("#current_creativecommons").hide();
            jQuery("#creativecommons_response").show();
        });
    });

    //-->
    </script>
    </dspace:layout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are running into is that the creative commons api is unable to recognise locale "pt_BR".

Change the cc license locale to this configuration to resolve the issue:

cc.license.locale = pt

Comment: Don't work, and when I select the creative commons license the options do not appear and it is not vinculated to item after submission.